# Why can't I or other internal testers open downloaded app from Google Play?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play, google-play-internal-testing

I have created an android game using **Unity**, and published a release through the Google Play Console. However, whenever I or anyone else downloads it, there is no "open" button, only "uninstall"

What can I do to fix this?

I also looked through my phone's files to see if I could open it manually, but it when I select the file, it only gives me the option to "uninstall" or "Force stop".